# Does Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood build on the saved game from Assassin's Creed II?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

Some games (like Mass Effect 2) build on the saved games from earlier versions by allowing the player to keep going with the choices they'd made earlier. Assassin's Creed isn't big on non-linearity, but my ACII character does have nice armor, weapons, and some cash.

Will AC: Brotherhood notice that saved game and pick up information from it or does Brotherhood always start from scratch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it will not.

Assassins Creed Brotherhood will always play exactly the same way regardless of whether you have an Assassins Creed II save game.

Comment: It does look like the sequence at the very beginning carries over your stuff, but then it pulls a Metroid Prime-style "Oops I dropped my stuff!" kinda deal, so it's a moot point.  (This also could have been my imagination, but I could swear my money was exactly the same quantity for that sequence.)

Comment: @Shinrai i think you're right about same money thing

Comment: Bit of a pointless piece of work if it gets rid of it all so soon, isn't it?

Comment: It's been a while since i played, but i tought the armor and weapon transfered over in the beginning aswell?

Comment: @RafaelCelerier It may, but at the same time, it might just always have you wearing the best armour and sword.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The money and equipment are the same amounts as when the second game ends in the vault. (Don't want to lose over 500,000 florin!)

Answer (score 0):

No.

At the end of Assassin's Creed 2, I had the Armor and Sword of Altair, 3/4 million Florins, and a 2nd Hidden Blade.

At the start of Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood, I had generic armor and sword, a little over 50k florins, and only the one Hidden Blade.

A short while into the game, I had no armor, no Florins, and still just the one Hidden Blade. It seems Ezio has forgotten much of his fighting skills.

Comment: Welcome to the arqade! You're certainly correct, but you're only repeating what was said in an answer from an entire decade ago. We tend to look for new information, in additional answers.

Answer (score -1):

I just started brotherhood and it definitely has all my stuff from ac II. haven't lost it yet. Kinda bummed now.